# How to create URLs without identifiers

Tags: php, apache, url, url-rewriting, url-routing

These days, I am seeing more a more, URL like this: `example.com/this_is_content_title`
I am not sure how this is done, or possible even. I know most sites use something like `example.com/108/some_text_here` with the `108` part being an identifier/id of the news but, how is it possible to append the title just after the domain name and how to fetch from database?

My guess it they are appending it using apache, but why can't we see the identifier and how do they search/find the content based on the text?

maybe:

```
$title = str_replace(array('_', '/'), '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE title = '$title'";
```

I am assuming that is how they retrieve the contents from database, even though it seems not efficient way to do it. Because, it would be much more speedy to search for an article based on id's instead of a whole sentences.

Anyway, if that is how they show the articles, how does one just append title into the URI?

Don't tell me it is something like this:

```
$row['title'] = 'I am title for some article';
echo "<a href='http://example.com/".str_replace(' ', '_', $row['title'])."'";
```

Comment: A lot of frameworks nowadays do url routing. One example is flask, where you can specify @app.route('/test/<id>') and the <id> is a value you can use to display dynamic content. I think nginx has support for this too.

Comment: You use a slug: 'awesome-article-please-read', generated upon saving, and stored in the db along with the rest of the article (id, title, text, date, etc), and use that for the lookup, as you would with IDs (make sure the slug is unique too). That is, the identifier is now the slug

Answer (score 1):

this is call seo url
you can see some samples here http://davidwalsh.name/htaccess-url

Comment: Link-only answer are discouraged, what if the original page gets moved or deleted? Also, the article you linked is not entirely relevant to the problem (only corrects the trailing slash)

Answer (score 1):

You are right, that is how it is done, and the string is indentifier here. Also workaround here would be ENUM of all identifiers but lets not go too deep into it.

It seems not efficient way for you, I see your point, but hey this action is only ~0,01sec slower and gives you a lot of advance on SEO because you have clean url, so nothing too bad there...

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain it very well but I was reading the Apache docs on URL rewriting and it is quite easy to do what I think they called a 'silent' redirect, so that without changing the URL client-side the server redirects all requests for `example.com/this_is_content_title` to `example.com/108/some_text_here` or for that matter `example.com/?id=108`.

Aside from server configuration, I think WordPress does this with PHP when you `enable pretty permalinks`, so the WordPress repos and codex might be a good place to look for more details.